# How to upload picture using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I can manage to insert data into the tblaccount. But the problem is the picture can't be uploaded. The tblaccount contains the right data of firstname, lastname, email, department, username, and password, but the picture remains blank even I've uploaded some images.

UPDATE: The picture can now be uploaded in the folder, but no luck in tblaccount. It only show blank data.

signup.php controller:

```
public function index()
{
    // set form validation rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('firstname', 'First Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('lastname', 'Last Name', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email Address', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[tblaccount.Email]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('department', 'Department', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|is_unique[tblaccount.Username]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|matches[password]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('picture', 'Image', 'trim|required');

    // submit
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        // fails
        $this->load->view('signup_view');
    }
    else
    {
        if(!empty($_FILES['picture']['name']))
        {
            $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/images/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
            $config['max_size'] = 10000000;
            $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

            //Load upload library and initialize configuration
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->initialize($config);

            if($this->upload->do_upload('picture'))
            {
                $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
            }
            else
            {
                $picture = '';
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                echo "<script>alert('JPG, JPEG, PNG and GIF type of file only is allowed and atleast 10MB of size');window.location = '".base_url("index.php/signup")."';</script>";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $picture = '';
        }
            $data = array(
                'First_Name' => $this->input->post('firstname'),
                'Last_Name' => $this->input->post('lastname'),
                'Email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                'Department' => $this->input->post('department'),
                'Username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'Password' => $this->input->post('password'),
                'Picture' => $picture
            );

            if ($this->account_model->insert($data))
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are successfully registered! Please login to access your profile!</div>');
                redirect('login');
            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
                redirect('signup');
            }
    }
}
```

signup.php view:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 well">
            <?php echo form_open_multipart('signup');?>
                <legend>Signup</legend>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">First Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('First_Name');?>"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('firstname'); ?></span>
                    </div>          

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Last Name</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('Last_Name');?>"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('lastname'); ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('Email');?>"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Department</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="department" placeholder="Department" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('Department');?>"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('department'); ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email">Username</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('Username');?>"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subject">Password</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subject">Confirm Password</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('cpassword'); ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subject">Profile Picture:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="picture" accept="image/*" type="file"/>
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('picture'); ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Signup</button>
                        <button name="cancel" type="reset" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</button>
                    </div>

            <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove required from validation check as it is not allowed to pass in image field ,when you check empty file field (!empty($_FILES['picture']['name']) then required validation already checked inside it , Secondly you have to check whether the directory is created or not and provide 777 permission to it . I have tested code by adding only these two check. Hope it help

```
 $this->form_validation->set_rules('picture', 'Image', 'trim'); /*Change in this line -- remove required*/
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            if (!empty($_FILES['picture']['name'])) {
                $config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images/';
                /*add 777 permission to directory*/  
                if (!is_dir($config['upload_path'])) {
                    mkdir($config['upload_path'], 0777, TRUE);
                }
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|gif';
                $config['max_size'] = 10000000;
                $config['file_name'] = $_FILES['picture']['name'];

                //Load upload library and initialize configuration
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);

                if ($this->upload->do_upload('picture')) {
                    $uploadData = $this->upload->data();
                    $picture = $uploadData['file_name'];
                } else {
                    $picture = '';
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    echo "<script>alert('JPG, JPEG, PNG and GIF type of file only is allowed and atleast 10MB of size');window.location = '" . base_url("index.php/signup") . "';</script>";
                }
            } else {
                $picture = '';
            }
            $data = array(
                'image' => $picture
            );

            $this->write_conn->db->insert('test', $data);
            if ($this->write_conn->db->insert('test', $data)) {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are successfully registered! Please login to access your profile!</div>');
            } else {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', '<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Oops! Error.  Please try again later!!!</div>');
            }
        }
```

Comment: I can now upload image in the location and also the data in tblaccount. My problem now is the upload button can upload anything like docs. And also what is the validation for it if it is empty? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for late reply , As I have checked in config the allowed type are jpg|jpeg|png|gif so only these files get uploaded nothing else and also validated if images is uploaded if it is not empty !empty($_FILES['picture']['name'] .You can check either through jquery or in else condition give error to user for not being empty.

Answer (score 0):

On your upload path

```
$config['upload_path'] = 'uploads/images/';
```

Try

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads/images/';
$config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . '/uploads/images/';
```

And I use form_open_multipart() form [helper](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart) make sure your folder correct permissions

On another note make sure you have named your file and class name correct where **signup.php** would be **Signup.php** Only the first letter should be uppercase on class and filename explained here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

```
<?php

class Signup extends CI_Controller {

}
```